# How do I write a grep function that does the following?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

Suppose I have list of words.
I want to get words that end in "se". How would I grep this file?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `se\>` as the pattern.

```
$ grep 'se\>' <<< $'abc\nhouse\nsegment'
house
```

Comment: Thanks! that works. What if I want words that end in "se" AND are less than 6 characters?

Comment: That doesn't actually change anything.  Maybe `\<\w{,3}se\>` instead.

Comment: @ephemient: Ah, yes, I forgot to anchor the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not too good at grep, if Perl will work (pre-installed on most linux systems) try 
`perl -nE '@words = split; for (@words) {say if /se$/}' filename`, which works on newer versions. `perl -ne '@words = split; for (@words) {print "$_\n" if /se$/}' filename` will work on all.

Comment: perl -nE '@words = split; for (@words) {say if /^.{0,3}se$/}' filename